# Is it possible to create a class level variable dynamically using python's type function?

Tags: python

Given the class

```
class A(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.x = 'hello'
```

one can recreate is dynamically with `type`.

```
type('A', (object,), {'x': 'hello'})
```

Is it possible to create class level variables with type?

```
class A(object): 
    my_class_variable = 'hello'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [154]: A = type('A', (object,), {'my_class_variable':'hello'})

In [155]: A.my_class_variable
Out[157]: 'hello'
```

In your first example, `type('A', (object,), {'x': 'hello'})`, `A.x` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute too.

To make a class with the `__init__` you posted, you would first need to define the `__init__` function, then make that `__init__` a class attribute:

```
In [159]: def __init__(self):
   .....:       self.x = 'hello'
   .....: 

In [160]: A2= type('A', (object,), {'__init__':__init__})

In [161]: 'x' in dir(A2)   
Out[161]: False            # x is not a class attribute

In [162]: 'x' in dir(A2()) 
Out[162]: True             # x is an instance attribute
```